# How can I create a PDF programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-print

I want to create a pdf with some labels and a image and a table with set of rows in iOS programmatically.

Please suggest some idea about this.

How can I enable it for Google cloud priniting in ios programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
void CreatePDFFile (CGRect pageRect, const char *filename) 
{   
// This code block sets up our PDF Context so that we can draw to it
CGContextRef pdfContext;
CFStringRef path;
CFURLRef url;
CFMutableDictionaryRef myDictionary = NULL;

// Create a CFString from the filename we provide to this method when we call it
path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename,
                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

// Create a CFURL using the CFString we just defined
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path,
                                     kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
CFRelease (path);
// This dictionary contains extra options mostly for 'signing' the PDF
myDictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0,
                                         &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                         &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextTitle, CFSTR("My PDF File"));
CFDictionarySetValue(myDictionary, kCGPDFContextCreator, CFSTR("My Name"));
// Create our PDF Context with the CFURL, the CGRect we provide, and the above defined dictionary
pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL (url, &pageRect, myDictionary);
// Cleanup our mess
CFRelease(myDictionary);
CFRelease(url);
// Done creating our PDF Context, now it's time to draw to it

// Starts our first page
CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext, &pageRect);

// Draws a black rectangle around the page inset by 50 on all sides
CGContextStrokeRect(pdfContext, CGRectMake(50, 50, pageRect.size.width - 100, pageRect.size.height - 100));

// This code block will create an image that we then draw to the page
const char *picture = "Picture";
CGImageRef image;
CGDataProviderRef provider;
CFStringRef picturePath;
CFURLRef pictureURL;

picturePath = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, picture,
                                         kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
pictureURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), picturePath, CFSTR("png"), NULL);
CFRelease(picturePath);
provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL (pictureURL);
CFRelease (pictureURL);
image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider (provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease (provider);
CGContextDrawImage (pdfContext, CGRectMake(200, 200, 207, 385),image);
CGImageRelease (image);
// End image code

// Adding some text on top of the image we just added
CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica", 16, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);
const char *text = "Hello World!";
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, 260, 390, text, strlen(text));
// End text

// We are done drawing to this page, let's end it
// We could add as many pages as we wanted using CGContextBeginPage/CGContextEndPage
CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);

// We are done with our context now, so we release it
CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
```

Comment: EDIT: Here's an example on GitHub using libHaru in an iPhone project.

Comment: How to create a tables in pdf ?

Comment: How to create(write data dynamically) multi pageed pdf in ios programatically ?